# Why my client could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority?

Tags: c#, security, ssl, https

When I am trying consuming a Web Service with a URL HTTPS it is causing this error message:

**[SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority.**

I have already read a solution to accept this trust between my client program (C#) and the HTTPS address:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
```

So my question is why my client could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority? Does somebody know? Because it seems that this solution is not safe.

Comment: Does the remote end have an invalid certificate or is it self signed?

Comment: We are suspecting that is an invalid certificate. Because in other environment this error not happens.

Comment: Well open it in a browser and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you so much David! Now it is clear for us that the problem is with certificate and via browser we could see many warnings and errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **.NET** core, you can set `CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None` and `RevocationMode nocheck`

```
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication =
    new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
    {
        CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
        RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
    };
```